# How do I achieve this route structure with search filter and tag using Vue Router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Newbie to Vue Router and really struggling to put this together even after reading the docs like 2 times

**What pages?**

- I have a news website where the page shows list of items on the left and shows details on right when clicked on item list

[image]

- I have a **filter search and tag** functionality on that page

**Default URL**

- '/' corresponds to home page with  **filter=latest** **search=empty string** and **tag=all** and shows latest posts in descending order of their published date with any tag on them

**Search**

- /news?search=china
- search query is not present in the URL when search is empty string

**Filter**

- /news?filter=likes
- filter has 3 values: 'likes', 'dislikes' and 'latest'
- filter query is not present in the URL when filter is 'latest'

**Tag**

- /news/trump will show all posts with the tag trump on them
- tag param is not present in the URL when tag is 'all'

**Combinations**

- Search, filter and tag can be combined together
- / where filter = latest, search = empty string and tag = all
- /news?filter=likes&search=china where filter = likes, search = china and tag = all
- /news/trump?filter=likes&search=china where filter = likes, search = china and tag = trump

**Item URLS**

- Clicking on an item in the list changes URL at the top to an item URL
- /news/:id/:title for an item when no tag is specified meaning tag=all
- /news/:tag/:id/:title for an item when clicking on an item while viewing say items under trump tag

**What have I tried?**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import Index from '~/pages/index'

Vue.use(Router)
export function createRouter() {
  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Index',
        component: Index,
      },
      {
        path: '/news',
        name: 'News',
        component: Index,

      },
      {
        path: '/news/:tag',
        name: 'TaggedNews',
        component: Index,
      },
      {
        path: '/news/:id([a-f0-9]{32})/:title',
        name: 'NewsItem',
        component: Index,
      },
      {
        path: '/news/:tag/:id([a-f0-9]{32})/:title',
        name: 'TaggedNewsItem',
        component: Index,
      },
    ],
  })
}
```

**What is the problem?**

- Lets say I am at /news?filter=likes&search=china , I click on an item and go to /news/123456/some-random-title now I have lost the query and search values if try to navigate to another list
- When I change my filter to latest it needs to be removed from URL
- When I set search to empty string it needs to be removed from URL
- If I enter /?filter=likes it should take me to /news?filter=likes
- If I enter /news I should go back to /
- If I enter /news/all I am back to /
- If I enter /news/all?search=china I am redirected to /news?search=china
- Basically the default values are managed in the URL by not showing them
- How do I differentiate between me changing the URL by pushing it vs user pressing back/forward buttons and the URL getting changed because of that?
- How do I achieve this?

Comment: Look into using navigation [guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) for most of these.